# find all lines that begin with `console` in notepad++

Tags: find, notepad++, newline

How do I find all lines that begin with `console` in notepad++?
there can be zero to any number of spaces or tabs before the word `console`

suppose i have a file as follows:

```
    'createdRow': function (row, data, index) {
        console.log("data is: "); console.log(data);
        fields=Object.keys(data)
        console.log("fields is: "); console.log(fields);
        noOfFields=fields.length
        console.log("noOfFields is: "); console.log(noOfFields);

        var highlightVal = 80;
        var highlightClassName = 'highlight';
        var counterIndexCount = 4;

        for (var i=1; i <= counterIndexCount; i++) {
            if (parseInt(data['counter'+ i].substring(0,2), 10) >= highlightVal) {
                $('td', row).eq(i).addClass(highlightClassName);
            } else {
                $('td', row).eq(i).removeClass(highlightClassName);
            }
        }
```

I thought I might have to do something like `\n console` using the Extended option in the bottom left of the find search. But could not get it to work.

for my reference:
similar q asked here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a regex (regular expression) search for this:

```
^( |\t)*console
```

The `^` matches the start of the line; `( |\t)*` matches any number of tabs or spaces; and `console`, of course, matches the text you're looking for.

If you want to match the whole line, add `.*` at the end:

```
^( |\t)*console.*
```

Answer (score 1):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Then in the search window:

Find what: `^\s*console\b`

then click on <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>
You'll find the lines in the find result window.

```
^        : Begining of line
\s*      : 0 or more any kind of space character
console  : literally 'console'
\b       : word boundary to make sure that is not matching 'consolefoobar'
```